# How to reject all zeros in any format regex

Tags: regex

I almost solve my problem, but I think I forgot or misplace one character. I want to reject zeros value, including this format 0.00.

```java
^((?!0+$)\d+)(\.0{2})$
```

[My Regex](https://regex101.com/r/ED2Ehf/1)

At first I only wanted to reject zero value, then I wrote `^(?!0+$)\d+$`
Then I have another requirement to only accept xxx.00 this format. two digits decimal. And ended up like `^((?!0+$)\d+)(\.0{2})$` 
It does reject number other than .00 format, but accepting 0.00. I did negate the zero at the first group, but why the regex accepting it?

```
0 //false
9 //false
1000.00 //true
.00 //false
10.00 //true
434543.12 //false
324.00 //true
40000 //false
0.00 //should be false but mine is true
000.00 //should be false but mine is true
```

I tried to regroup and reposition but nothing work.

Comment: Maybe `^(?![0.]+$)\d+(?:\.0{2})?$`? See https://regex101.com/r/ED2Ehf/2

Comment: `I want to reject zero's value` ... what does this actually mean?  Can you explain it to us?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not only 0.00 ,  but also 0000.00 , any digit zero .

Comment: I think a better solution would be a two-step process: Step one to verify the format; And step two to check for zeroes. Step two, checking for all zero, you don't need regular expressions for that, just iterate over the string and if there's a non-zero digit character (the dot excluded) just return "true".

Comment: `any digit zero` ... why do both `9` and `0` fail then?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because I only want to accept number in xx.00 format. Since I have solved that part, I didn't re-asked that part

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks It works! I had tried to put `?:` in front of `\.` but I didn't put the `[0.]` . I think the key is that part.

Comment: Now if you use the regex suggested by @WiktorStribiżew then please be sure to document it thoroughly. Because it is basically undecipherable for all but regex experts. This is the problem with regular expressions, they can be incredibly powerful, but they are also incredibly unfriendly and looks more like line-noise than anything else. When the solution is something that complex, then you're probably better of with something simpler which can be easily read, understood and maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you could simply use

```
^[1-9]\d*\.00$
```

See your [updated demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ED2Ehf/4)

- If you want to allow leading zeros, [add `0*` at start](https://regex101.com/r/ED2Ehf/6).
- If you want to allow [without `.00`, make that part optional](https://regex101.com/r/ED2Ehf/9).

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^(?![0.]+$)\d+\.0{2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ED2Ehf/10)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![0.]+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are one or more zeros or dots only to the end of the string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\.0{2}` - a sequence of `.` and two zeros
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake. Your solution is accepting number not in .00 format. Probably I focused too much on 0.00 then I didn't see the others. `9` and `40000` should be rejected

Comment: @chronos14 Then, remove the `?`. Note that `(?![0.]+$)` is a generic regex way to avoid matching int or floats that are equal to zero with consuming patterns like `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`.